# Unable to detect GPU using ssh to Google colab

Tags: python, ssh, google-colaboratory, ngrok

I have deployed an ssh tunnel to google collab using ngrok, and it works reasonably well. Problems arose when I wanted to get information about the video card and the version of CUDA on it. Since I received an error stating that all CUDA devices are busy or missing.

```
import paramiko

host = '2.tcp.ngrok.io'
user = 'root'
secret = 'I will not say'
port = 11568

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=secret, port=port)

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(f'nvidia-smi')

stdout_text = stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
stderr_text = stderr.read().decode('utf-8')

print(f'Output: {stdout_text}\nError: {stderr_text}')
client.close()
```

I got `Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch`

But in google collab i got normal result without any error.

```
Fri Dec  3 21:03:10 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 495.44       Driver Version: 460.32.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   71C    P0    75W / 149W |      0MiB / 11441MiB |     12%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried to use `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = '0'`
But it gave no results...